# excel Error 13 vba type mismatch for columns advancemenet macro

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I have tried to run this code in order to advance certain columns

#### Sheet1

[image]

#### Sheet2

[image]

But my code always produce the same `error 13` error:

```
Sub TEST_REPLACECOLUMNS_TEST()

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    
    Dim NumofColumns As Long
    Dim NumofMoveMortg As Long
    Dim NumofMoveOth As Long
    Dim AssetNum As Long
    
    Dim FirstColumn As String
    Dim StartColumn As String
    Dim EndColumn As String
    Dim MyRange As String
    Dim StartMortg As String

    NumofColumns = 3
    NumofMoveMort = 15
    NumofMoveOth = 1
    
    AssetNum = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b3").End(xlToLeft).Row
    
    StartMortg = "C"
    FirstColumn = "A"
    
    StartColumn = Chr(Asc("FirstColumn") + NumofColumns * (AssetNum - 1))
    EndColumn = Chr(Asc("FirstColumn") + NumofColumns * (AssetNum - 1) + NumofColumns)
    
    Let MyRange = StartColumn & ":" & EndColumn
    
    Columns("myRange").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="$A", Replacement:="$" & (Chr(Asc("StartMortg") + NumofMoveMortg * (AssetNum - 1))), LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False

End Sub
```

the new code after removal of the quotation marks around the variables that are being used in the formulaes. I have also added "LookIn:=xlFormulas"

Sub TEST_REPLACECOLUMNS_TEST()

```
Dim NumofColumns As Long
Dim NumofMoveMortg As Long
Dim NumofMoveOth As Long
Dim AssetNum As Long

Dim FirstColumn As String
Dim StartColumn As String
Dim EndColumn As String
Dim MyRange As String
Dim StartMortg As String

NumofColumns = 3
NumofMoveMort = 15
NumofMoveOth = 1

StartMortg = "C"
FirstColumn = "A"

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
 
AssetNum = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b3").End(xlToLeft).Row

Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

StartColumn = Chr(Asc(FirstColumn) + NumofColumns * (AssetNum - 1))
EndColumn = Chr(Asc(FirstColumn) + NumofColumns * (AssetNum - 1) + NumofColumns)

Let MyRange = StartColumn & ":" & EndColumn

Columns(MyRange).Select
Selection.Replace What:="$A", Replacement:="$" & (Chr(Asc(StartMortg) + NumofMoveMort * (AssetNum - 1))), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
```

Comment: On what line are you recieving run time error 13?

Comment: Change `Columns("myRange").Select` to `Columns(MyRange).Select`

Comment: thanks all. @MilesFett I have removed the quotation marks around the defined variables! this is the new code but getting a new error now! "Application-defined or object-defined error, Run-time error '1004' " and it doesn't show the place of the code mistake

Comment: Take out the `LookIn:=xlFormulas`